# javascript split with multi separator & returning used separator to array?

Tags: javascript

I have String

```
var t = '@qf$q>@gf';
```

and array of separators

```
var s = '@$>';
```

I would like to have a function which returns:

```
var a = f(t,s);
// a is array = ["@","qf","$","q",">","@","gf"];
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
'@qf$q>@gf'.match(/[@$>]|[^@$>]+/g)
```

The regular expression `/[@$>]|[^@$>]+/g` matches all occurrences of either a single separator character (`[@$>]`) or any sequence of one or more non-separator characters (`[^@$>]+`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:

```
var t = '@qf$q>@gf';
var s = '@$>';

var finalArray = [];
var tmpString = '';
var found = false;
for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j<s.length; j++) {
    if (t[i] == s[j]) {
      found = true;
      if (tmpString != '') {
        finalArray.push(tmpString);
      }
      finalArray.push(t[i]);
      tmpString = '';
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    tmpString += t[i];
  }
  found = false;
}
if (tmpString != '') {
  finalArray.push(tmpString);
}
```

It will output:

```
["@", "qf", "$", "q", ">", "@", "gf"]
```

Here is the associated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cf8LA/

---

### Edit: simplified version

```
var t = '@qf$q>@gf';
var s = '@$>';

var finalArray = [];
var tmpString = '';
for (var i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
  if (s.indexOf(t[i]) >= 0) {
    if (tmpString != '') {
      finalArray.push(tmpString);
    }
    finalArray.push(t[i]);
    tmpString = '';
  } else {
    tmpString += t[i];
  }
}
if (tmpString != '') {
  finalArray.push(tmpString);
}
```

Updated jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cf8LA/1/